# Magento 2: Make sales without stock

Tags: magento2, sales-order, out-of-stock

I need to allow the customer to compare the product even if there is no stock, in fact I need my simple item to behave when out of stock as if it were normally available.
What would be the best way to approach this?

After a lot of searching on the web, I didn't find anything that could help me with this ..

I thank you for your attention :)

Magento 2.3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can enabled a product to be setup so that its stock is not managed. It is in the inventory section and it can be done for one product or many in batch.. Of course, it can be done across the whole catalog but I gather you are after setting it up only for specific product

Comment: Yes, that solves, thanks